# Error when trying to print the average of a vector

Tags: java, vector

I'm new at Java, I'm trying to make a 3-dimensional vector with the numbers 10-28 in it.

I also want to print the average of all the numbers, this is my code so far:

```
    int[][][] v = {{{10, 12, 14}, {16, 18, 20}, {22, 24, 26}},
                   {{11, 13, 15}, {17, 19, 21}, {23, 25, 28}}};


    for (int[][] n : v) {
        for (int[] b : n) {
            for (int c : b) {
                System.out.print(c + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    { 
        int x = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < v.length; i++)
        x = 18 + v[i];
        double average = x / v.length;




    }
}
```

Though I get an error when I'm doing the loop part of it.

Comment: Hi fsociety1337, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you tell us exactly what error you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to get the value of each position.

```
int total = 0;
int numberOfElements = 0;
for (int[][] n : v) {
    for (int[] b : n) {
        for (int c : b) {
            numberOfElements++;
            total += c;
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
int average = total / numberOfElements;
System.out.println(average);
```